# Ho to Change Author ID from SharePoint list to names in Power BI?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi

I am creating a dashboard with share Point online list. I want to show number of task created by each person. But, the report is showing numbers (Author ID) How do I change to names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the detail level steps.

Step-1: Connect to the SharePoint List.

Step-2: Click on "Edit Queries"

Step-3: Click "Choose Columns"

Step-4: Choose your columns and "Author"

[image]

Step-5: Click on symbol given as shown in the image

[image]

Step-6: Choose the column "Title"

[image]

And now you will have your name.

[image]

Let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: Thanks It worked!

Comment: But we couldnt get assigned to ID like this?

Comment: you should check other properties available in the checklist box. You will get the name of the property that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I have a question on this. Once it has run and I have the name.  How do I save it.  I don't see that column in my original excel.  Do I have to do a save as?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121585)